# convert 16-bit c++ inline __asm to 32-bit and remove far pointer

Tags: c++, assembly, x86, inline-assembly, x86-16

here is the code in 16-bit c++ compiler.

```
//restore interrupt
void CAzimuth::restoreISR()
{
    __asm{
        cli
        mov ax,205h
        mov bl,0fh
        mov cx,seg OldInt
        mov dx,offset OldInt
        int 31h
        sti
   }
}

//install interrupt
void CAzimuth::installISR()
{
    unsigned int u1,u2;
    __asm{
        //access the original vector
        cli
        mov ax,204h
        mov bl,0fh
        int 31h
        mov u1,cx
        mov u2,dx
        sti
    }

    OldInt=(INTPTR)(_MK_FP(u1,u2));

    __asm{
        //fill in new interrupt vector
        cli
        mov ax,205h
        mov bl,0fh
        mov cx,seg NewInt
        mov dx,offset NewInt
        int 31h
        sti
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the 16 bit platform and what's the 32 bit platform? This code won't work in Windows or Linux, unless it's in a driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This an ancient DOS Protected Mode Interface system call to set a protected mode interrupt vector. See eg http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/dpmi/api/310205.html.  The compiler was probably DJGPP. Porting this to a different OS and/or runtime system will require a redesign from scratch to reimplement whatever functionality the interrupt handlers provided under DPMI. Good luck to you with that. Could be anything from simple to near impossible.